# how to query DB With long time against shot time in asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, asp.net-core, dapper

I have a date input field with the same day as what is in the database but different time

for instance, the date in the database table like this `2020-06-30 17:50:01.376`

The input date from user is like `2020-06-30 00:00:00`
I can determine the date users will input so I decided to use short date like `2020-06-30`

This is my query that is returning null

```
product = conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<Products>("select TranDate, ProductNo from Products where ProductNo =@ProductNo AND TranDate =@TranDate", new { ProductNo = item.ProductNo , TranDate = "2020-06-30" });
```

It works fine if But if I change it to

```
product = conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<Products>("select TranDate, ProductNo from Products where ProductNo =@ProductNo AND TranDate =@TranDate", new { ProductNo = item.ProductNo , TranDate = "2020-06-30 17:50:01.376" });
```

Comment: You can update your query to `select TranDate, ProductNo from Products where ProductNo =@ProductNo AND CAST(TranDate AS DATE) =@TranDate`

Comment: Use parametrized queries , the datetime format could change by the db culture

Comment: In c# the DateTime Date() method truncates the date to midnight at the start of the day which is what you want to do to get 2020-06-30.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty your suggestion worked for me, can you properly make it an answer so I can mark it as useful. someone else might need it in future

Comment: @codefromitaly I will do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Query as below. Cast the db column date time to date and compare it with your input parameter.

```
SELECT TranDate
    ,ProductNo
FROM Products
WHERE ProductNo = @ProductNo
    AND CAST(TranDate AS DATE) = @TranDate
```